# How to get the target location of a Junction if the target directory does not exist?

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems

I have a junction from `A` -> `B`.
B does not exist, but I want to read from `A` the target of the junction (`B`).

However I can't make this work (filename = `A`):

```
// directoryHandle.isInvalid == true
var directoryHandle = CreateFile(filename, EFileAccess.GenericRead, EFileShare.Read | EFileShare.Write, IntPtr.Zero, ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting, EFileAttributes.BackupSemantics, IntPtr.Zero);
StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(1024);
// path is empty string
var res = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(directoryHandle, path, path.Capacity, 0);
```

`GetFinalPathNameByHandle` returns the location of the junction if B exists. But if B does not exist, I receive an invalid file handle so that the call to `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` also fails.

**Question**: How do I get the target of a junction if the target directory does not exist?

---

Here are the method definitions:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
    string lpFileName,
    EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
    EFileShare dwShareMode,
    IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
    ECreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition,
    EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetFinalPathNameByHandleW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern int GetFinalPathNameByHandle([In] SafeFileHandle hFile, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder path, int bufLen, int flags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask the junction directly.

To determine the type, use `FindFirstFile` (or `GetFileInformationByHandleEx(FileAttributeTagInfo)` if you already have a handle). The `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` bit must be set in the file attributes and the tag must be `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT` or `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK`.

If all checks pass, call `CreateFile` with the `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flags. Now call `DeviceIoControl(FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT)` to read the [`REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_reparse_data_buffer) (allocate `MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE` bytes for it). Look at the tag type to find `PathBuffer` and `SubstituteNameOffset`+`SubstituteNameLength` to find where in the buffer the path is.

You can find C# example code on [Codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21202/Reparse-Points-in-Vista)...